# iOS client id for App-Engine push notification

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java) that comes with the Google Paper on  [Orchestrating iOS Push Notifications on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/ios-push-notifications/#id.mpqb4ttxlxec). 
In the `Configuration.java` file there is the following line:

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "<!!! INSERT YOUR CLIENT ID FOR IOS HERE !!!>";
```

Where do I find this `client id for iOS?` and is there anywhere else that it should go? such as in the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a client id for ios On the Google developer console.
Go to "Credentials", then click on "Create new Key" under "Public API access"

[image: screenshot from google developer console]

Then click on "ios Key":

[image]

And then, thanks to this documentation's section  :
[documentation on API Key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#generatingdevkeys), you will understand that this key is used for bi-directionnal communication between the server and the client app.